# Python loop in dictionary

Tags: python

I have two lists structured like:

```
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [{'name':'foo',  'address':'bar'}, {'name':'foo1', 'address':'bar1'}]
```

I thing is that i want to append the list1 into list2 and create something like:

```
new_list = [{'name':'foo', 'address':'bar', 'num':'1'}, {'name':'foo1','address':'bar1', 'num':'2'}]
```

how can this be acheived?

Comment: Those are `tuple` not `list`.

Comment: `new_list = [dict(num=n, **d) for n,d in zip(list1, list2)]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
for n, d in zip(list1, list2):
    d['num']=n
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple for loop

```
for i, j in enumerate(list2):
    j.update({'num': list1[i]})
```